# Getting an error on runnin 'mvn clean install'

Tags: apache, maven

[ERROR] Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-enforcer-plugin:1.3.1 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-enforcer-plugin:jar:1.3.1: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-enforcer-plugin:pom:1.3.1 from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Connection to http://repo.maven.apache.org refused: Connection refused -> [Help 1]

Comment: Try running the command again.

Comment: Please check your internet connection

Comment: It's fine and working.

Comment: My internet connection I mean

Answer (score 2):

It seems you do not have internet access

if you are using any proxy then you might have to add below tags in settings.xml

```
<proxies>
<proxy>
  <id>optional</id>
  <active>true</active>
  <protocol>http</protocol>
  <username></username>
  <password></password>
  <host></host>
  <port></port>
  <nonProxyHosts>localhost|127.*.*.*</nonProxyHosts>
</proxy>
</proxies>
```